# Raspberry Pi 2 - Redirect audio out to /dev/stdin?

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi

What I am trying to do is redirect all audio from the Pi to a partiticular program (PiFm).

PiFm supports reading from stdin (For like MP3's and such) How can one redirect audio, in wav format, to /dev/stdin.

Any help would be great! Thanks!

EDIT pifm reads from stdin: "pifm -" or "pifm /dev/stdin" either works, but the problem I have is I need to know the syntax for redirecting the pi's audio to the stdin pipe. (Using libav ffmpeg or whatever.)

EDIT2: my main goal in a nut shell is run all audio to PiFm (FM transmitter program for the RPi+RPi2) so that all audio can be heard on a nearby radio receiver (Like a handheld radio/MP3 device)

Comment: It seem like you're really asking for 'what program can read wav files from stdin', which probably is off topic here on StackOverflow. At least improve your Q by describing how PiFM reads from stdin, i.e. `PiFm < my.mp3` ? As with so many off-topic questions, and interesting problem. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, updated the question for you.

Comment: "pifm -" is what reads stdin.

Comment: There is no universal way of doing this unless you are running a system-wide audio daemon.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams my main goal in a nut shell is run all audio to PiFm (FM transmitter program for the RPi+RPi2) so that all audio can be heard on a nearby radio receiver (Like a handheld radio/MP3 device)

Comment: Are you running a system-wide audio daemon?

Comment: Yes, alsa I believe is the default for Raspbian.

Comment: so, a. microphone attached to raspberrypi, b. system-wide audio daemon running on Rpi, c. send sound from microphone via daemon to PiFm d. pifm sends to another machine? Is this your project's intended flow? (I'm just interested in this problem but won't have much to offer in the way of help). But, do you know about http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com ? You can use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask a moderator to move it there. Good Luck! (either way).

Comment: Well not a microphone, but all audio (or the audio that comes from Kodi) to pifm.

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34791597/how-to-modify-a-live-file-stream gives you some ideas? Good luck.

Comment: ALSA is not a daemon.