# How to modify a live file stream

Tags: linux, unix

I have a raspberry pi sending audio to my desktop, I then run pocketsphinx on it. The problem is the file quickly becomes too big. I would like to basically empty the file, keep its formatting, and have the pipe still write to it. Is this possible?

What I have now,

```
arecord -D plughw:1,0 -f S16_LE -r 16000 | ssh -C mingram@192.168.86.101 sox - pipe.wav
```

and on interval,

```
pocketsphinx_continuous -hmm /usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/en-us/en-us -dict ~/4568.dic -lm ~/4568.lm -infile ~/pipe.wav > ~/ButlerAssistant/newWords.log
```

I tried to do a `cat baseFormatFile.wav >> pipe.wav` on an interval but it didn't appear to actually overwrite it.

Edit: I meant tried to do `cat baseFormatFile.wav > pipe.wav` I don't want to append the file.

Edit #2: I did a `sox pipe.wav pipe.wav trim 0 10` But then the pipe stops writing to it. I also tried `sox baseFormatFile.wav pipe.wav trim 0 02` but it wouldn't change it unless the pipe was stopped.

Final edit: I think `cat baseFormatFile.wav > pipe.wav` actually worked, it just wasn't showing up in ls -l. It is reducing computation time and not showing old results so I mark it a success.

Comment: Yeah, I was about to edit to say I did cat baseFormatFile.wav > pipe.wav not >>

Comment: If you've figured out an answer to your own question, please add your solution as an answer below and give yourself a checkmark. You won't get points for answering your own question, but at least it will remove this question from the pool of unanswered ones, so that others don't waste time on a problem that has already been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `cat baseFormatFile.wav > pipe.wav actually worked`, it just wasn't showing up in ls -l. It is reducing computation time and not showing old results so I mark it a success.